# What happened to my disk volumes

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am new to amazon ec2. I created virtual machines using centos AMI.

I also created disk volumes of 50GB for each VM as you can see below

[image]

But if I go inside any of my VMs, and do `df -h` it says

```
[root@ip-172-31-0-64 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvde       7.8G  3.0G  4.5G  41% /
tmpfs           3.6G     0  3.6G   0% /dev/shm
cm_processes    3.6G     0  3.6G   0% /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process
```

Well that's not 50GB I assigned.

If I right click on any of the volumes then attach/detach and everything is greyed out.

So my question is what is going wrong? why don't I see 50GB worth of disk space mounted on my VM?

Answer (score 1):

wait... I think I solved the problem by

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/xvde
```

let me know if this is correct way of solving this or not.

but after running this command I can see

```
[root@ip-172-31-0-64 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvde        50G  3.0G   44G   7% /
tmpfs           3.6G     0  3.6G   0% /dev/shm
cm_processes    3.6G     0  3.6G   0% /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process
```